# Trying to move one part of my UL to the left

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using a simply `UL` as my `navbar`, and I am trying to separate the 1 item of the `UL` and put it to the left side of the page, and keep the other 3 centered, however i cant seem to get it working. I've tried wrapping it in a span and floating it, I've tried making a new UL but that just causes them to be on different lines.

I literally just want the homepage button to be aligned to the left and the rest of the buttons to be centered. Maybe I am missing something obvious.

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 10px 0 0 0 ;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 0 15px;
}

a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
<nav>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li id="homepage"><a href="#">AG Designs</a></li>
            <li id="aboutmebutton"><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
            <li id="portfoliobutton"><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li id="contactbutton"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Have you tried using bootstrap? You would be able to build much more flexible/response user interfaces. See this link https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

Answer (score 1):

This is one solution, making the first item **absolute position**

Add this to ur css

```
#homepage {
  position:absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

Doing this, it will center the next 3 items to the center of the page, and push the homepage div to the left

> Open the following snippet in full page view

```css
ul {
  position:relative;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#homepage {
  position:absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <nav>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li id="homepage"><a href="#">AG Designs</a></li>
        <li id="aboutmebutton"><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
        <li id="portfoliobutton"><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li id="contactbutton"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: this can cause an overlap on smaller screens

Answer (score 1):

You can select the first child and float it to the left like so:

```
li:first-child {
  float: left;
}
```

> **EDIT:** Added jQuery to achieve the desired result. It calculates the width of the first element and removes the left margin of the second `li` element.

Full code below:

```js
var firstChildWidth = $( "#homepage" ).width();

$( "ul li:nth-child(2)" ).css( "margin-left", -firstChildWidth + "px" );
```

```css
.navbar {
  background-color: yellow;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0 ;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

li:first-child {
  float: left;
  padding: 0px;
}

a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar">
  <nav>
      <div>
          <ul>
              <li id="homepage"><a href="#">AG Designs</a></li>
              <li id="aboutmebutton"><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
              <li id="portfoliobutton"><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
              <li id="contactbutton"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

> EDIT: Added some jQuery to achieve the desired result

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. This indeed puts it to the left, but now the rest of the LI items are no longer centered, they are slightly to the right of center

Comment: Yes, you are right because it still takes into account the first element to be apart of it. That is why @GautamNaik solution is better than mine ;)

Comment: @AdamGamble I added some jQuery to achieve the desired result with this option.

Answer (score -1):

add 
style="padding-left:50px;"
in your second li